# unable to debug directx interop com in the default windows phone 8 project in visual studio 2012

Tags: windows-phone-8, interop, directx

I created the default vc++ windows phone 8 directx/xaml solution. It created two project files. one xaml project and another native directx com interop dll. I checked my project is in debug mode, but still I'm unable to debug/step through the com interop dll code, but can step through cs code..

any idea how I can debug directx dll?

Answer (score 0):

Open your XAML C# project properties, go to debug tab and select "Native only" in "UI Task" combobox in "Debugger Type" section.

The reason for your problem is that there is no mixed-mode (both .NET and Native) debugger for Windows Phone, so you have to choose which code you would like to debug prior to running your application.